# Proper way to reference cells in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to reference columns and rows in my pandas dataframe and been getting some keyerrors.

The dataframe head is

[image]

I created two more dataframes that will contain values of all students that passed (with result=1) and failed (result = 0)

```
fail=data[data[:]['Result']==0]
passed=data[data[:]['Result']==1]
```

Now I want to plot a graph ( scatter plot ) of all the values of failed in exam 1 (in x-axis) and failed in exam 2 (in y-axis)

I tried using slice but it keeps resulting in an error

Attempt

```
passed[:][0]    #Does not print the first column of the passed dataframe
```

It gives the error

```
KeyError: 0
```

I have two queries

1. When do we use loc and iloc and when do we use slicing in pandas dataframes
2. When do we use [ [ ] ] double squared brackets to return a dataframe , I assumed we would do it while making the fail and passed dataframe but it was working with one [ ] which I heard returned a series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, the canonical way to do what you are doing is:

```
fail   = data[data['Result']==0]
passed = data[data['Result']==1]
```

Which is short-hand for

```
fail   = data.loc[data['Result']==0, :]
passed = data.loc[data['Result']==1, :]
```

`loc` is for slicing by labels, while `iloc` is for slicing by index (ie, if you know which row/column numbers you want).

The distinction between single and double brackets is as follows: if you return more than one column, Pandas will by necessity return a dataframe. If your query returns a single column, Pandas will by default return a Series. If you use double brackets, it will give you a dataframe of shape `(num_rows, 1)`. In your case, it doesn't matter, since you are returning multiple columns.

Finally, if you're using Pandas earlier than version `1.0.0`, you should use copies of the dataframes:

```
fail   = data[data['Result']==0].copy()
passed = data[data['Result']==1].copy()
```

This is to prevent the notorious [`SettingWithCopyWarning`](https://www.dataquest.io/blog/settingwithcopywarning/) if you later make changes.

Comment: Now how do I fetch all rows and a single column of the fail/passed dataframe

Using passed[:][0]  did not help

Comment: Yes, because you used an integer (0) which requires `iloc`, whereas `loc` is the default method. Also by default all rows are returned, so you can do just `passed['column']` or `fail['column']`. If you have further questions I highly recommend reading [this](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/getting_started/10min.html) and then posting another question if necessary.